# How to toggle CoreData CloudKit sync during App runtime

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I'm currently developing a SwiftUI based app with Core Data and CloudKit sync with the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`.

I found different solutions how to toggle CloudKit sync of the Core Data during runtime, also here on stack overflow. The basic idea of these solutions is the following.

1. instantiate a new `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`
2. set `storeDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = nil`
3. load persistence store

Most solutions recommend to restart the app manually to avoid exactly my problem described below.

**Issues**

So far so good. How can I distribute the new viewContext through my SwiftUI app during runtime. In the main App I distributed the viewContext during startup via `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` and it seems not be updated automatically after a reinitialization of `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`.

```
var body: some Scene {
     WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistence.container.viewContext)
        }
}
```

After deactivating the CloudKit sync I receive the following error when I try to add a new entity.

```
[error] warning: Multiple NSEntityDescriptions claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'TestEntity' so +entity is unable to disambiguate.
```

Any ideas? Is it a problem of the `@Environment` concept?

**Update: 12.12.2021: Fixed re-injection of the viewContext**

I fixed the issue to re-inject the `viewContext` by the following changes.

First I introduced the `@Published var persistenceContainerReloaded: Int = 0` attribute to the `Persistence` class. Every time, I toggle the CloudKit Sync, I switch between `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` and `NSPersistentContainer`. Afterwards I increase the attribute `persistenceContainerReloaded` by 1. The line `.id(persistence.persistenceContainerReloaded)` triggers the reload of the full view hierarchy. Now every view uses the correct viewContext instance.

```
@main
struct TargetShooterApp: App {
    @StateObject var persistence: Persistence = Persistence.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistence.container.viewContext)
                .id(persistence.persistenceContainerReloaded)
        }
    }
}
```

But I still facing some issues with my solution.  I still see CoreData+CloudKit debug outputs in the terminal, although the `storeDescription.cloudKitContainerOptionsis` nil. The device is still able to sync local changes to other devices, but is not capable to receive changes made on other devices. After the restart of the app, everything works as expected. It seems, there is still a background process `NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate` running, uploading CoreData changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello! 

Have you managed to find any solution to this? I've stumbled on the same rock, trying to implement toggle for my iCloud sync in SwiftUI app.